# Acessar a alocação faz programa parar de funcionar

Tags: c, funções, arquivo, struct, alocação

Estou com um problema pra acessar uma struct de inscritos

```
typedef struct Inscrito {
     char nome[50];
     float cadastro;
     float nota;
};

Inscrito *inscritos = NULL;
```

ela esta como variavel global e toda vez que eu acesso ela de alguma forma (seja pra verificar um erro ou pra botar os valores dentro dela depois de alocada ela da  erro)

(dados é a variavel do arquivo .txt que eu abri)

```
int Conta_MaioresNotas(FILE *Dados){

float NotaMin;
char info[20];
float numero;
int contador = 0, i = 0;

printf("Voce escolheu as maiores notas\n");
printf("Apartir de qual nota voce quer? ");
scanf("%f", &NotaMin);

while(!feof(Dados)){
    fscanf(Dados,"%s", &info);
    numero = atof(info);
    if(numero && numero > NotaMin && numero < 1001){
        contador++;
        printf("%.2f\n", numero);
    }
}
printf("%d\n", contador);
VoltaInicio(Dados);


inscritos = (Inscrito *) malloc(contador*sizeof(Inscrito));

if(inscritos == NULL) {printf("Deu erro meu amigo\n"); exit(-1);}


 while(!feof(Dados)){
    fscanf(Dados,"%s ", &info);
    numero = atof(info);
    if(!numero){
        strcat(inscritos[i].nome, " ");
        strcat(inscritos[i].nome, info);
        }
    else{
        if(numero > 1000){
            inscritos[i].cadastro = numero;

            }
        else{
            if(numero > NotaMin){
                inscritos[i].nota = numero;
                i++;
                }
            else{
                strcpy(inscritos[i].nome,"");
                inscritos[i].cadastro = 0.0;
                }
            }
        }    
}
VoltaInicio(Dados);
```

Esse while que da o erro, mas não to entendendo por que, o programa da pau e fecha "O programa parou de funcionar. Um problema fez com que o programa parasse de funcionar"

```
/*printf("Cadatrados filtrados:\n");
for(i = 0; i < contador; i++)
{
    printf("Nome: %s\nCadastro: %f\nNota: %.2f\n\n", inscritos[i].nome, inscritos[i].cadastro, inscritos[i].nota);
}*/


return contador;
}
```

comentei esse for pra mostrar que não é ele que ta dando erro, so pra poder mostrar o codigo ate o final

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
(ja tentei passar o ponteiro inscritos para a função e deu o mesmo erro)

Answer (score 0):

Da forma que o código foi apresentado fica um pouco difícil determinar com certeza qual é o problema, até porquê ele não foi informado por completo, mas existem algumas considerações.

Primeiramente, não encorajo o uso de variáveis globais. Entendo a facilidade que isso proporciona mas pode ser responsável por estes erros se não prestar atenção no que faz. É importante observar que variáveis globais podem ser alteradas em qualquer lugar, então é muito fácil você acabar liberando ou sobrescrevendo dados de variáveis globais através de um fluxo de execução não previsto. Desenvolva seu software tendo em mente os caminhos em que o código poderá ser executado. Faça com que suas funções exerçam apenas **uma** tarefa, e não funções que fazem tudo que é para ser feito.

Quanto ao código apresentado, primeiramente acredito que não copiou diretamente do que fez porque há um erro logo na declaração da *struct*, ao usar esta notação de *struct* com *typedef* (o que é louvável, aprecio a prática conforme você fez), é necessário definir o novo nome após o término da declaração da *struct*, antes do ponto e vírgula, no seu exemplo:

```
typedef struct Instrucao{
  ...
} Instrucao; //<---Erro
```

Só por isso o exemplo fornecido já não executaria, mas não acredito que seja o caso.

Também não acredito que seja o caso de liberação de memória, mas tenha em mente que você deve liberar a memória alocada na variável *instrucoes* utilizando a função *free()*, devido à alocação dinâmica realizada.

Quanto ao seu erro específico, também deve notar que dentro do *While* que você suspeita ter um erro, você utiliza a função **strcat**, e ela, como o nome diz, realiza uma **concatenação** de strings. Inicialmente o nome em questão está vazio, não possui absolutamente nada, então há um pequeno problema em querer concatenar uma string à nada, o valor está literalmente *vazio*, mas a maioria dos compiladores não reclamarão disso superficialmente, se você utilizar um analisador de execução como *valgrind*, perceberá que ele reclamará de alguns erros relacionados à instruções que dependem de memória que ainda não foi inicializada (sua string antes de concatenar qualquer coisa).

Esta concatenação é também perigosa porque a variável *nome* na sua *struct Instrucao* foi declarada como tendo tamanho máximo de 50 caracteres, portanto, é possível que alguma das concatenações que você está realizando ultrapasse 50 caracteres, o que quer dizer que um dos nomes possui mais do que 50 caracteres, ou uma concatenação indevida está acontecendo e ultrapassando o limite de caracteres que você alocou, causando o que é chamado de **stack smashing**, basicamente você está usando mais caracteres do que informou.

Se o problema não for no nome nas instruções, pode estar no vetor de caracteres *info*, que tem suporte para apenas 20 caracteres, então um dos nomes ou sobrenomes pode ultrapassar 20 caracteres e causar o erro informado.

Acontece que nem sempre ultrapassar o tamanho que você alocou causará um erro como esse, o que acontece é um **undefined behaviour** ou **comportamento indefinido**, às vezes pode funcionar, às vezes não, será variável conforme a execução do seu programa e, portanto, não será confiável usá-lo. É importante que você mude essas strings para uma alocação dinâmica ou aumente o tamanho delas para ver se isso resolve o problema em questão.